Combinatorial proof that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k {2n \choose n+k}=\frac{1}{2}n{2n \choose n}$
I'd like to find a combinatorial/algebraic proof of the identity:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k{2n \choose n+k}=\frac{1}{2}n{2n \choose n}$$
The only proof of this that I've been able to find on the Internet, uses the Egorychev method, which is a bit excessive in my opinion.

I'll post the answer I came up with.
Hint: it involves non-returning walks on the number-line.
In addition, I wonder if there are even simpler ways of showing this?

The easiest approach is probably to replace the $k$ factor on the left hand side by $n+k$ (the difference $n$ can be factored out of the sum), and then rewrite $\left(n+k\right)\dbinom{2n}{n+k}$ as $2n\dbinom{2n-1}{n+k-1}$. Now the $2n$ can again be factored out of the sum and the rest dealt with in a standard way (the sum of the left half of the $m$-th row of Pascal's triangle is $2^m / 2 = 2^{m-1}$, at least when $m$ is odd).

Much simpler! Thank you both!

Restating the Problem
First, rearranging the equality:
$$2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n}{2n \choose n+k}={2n \choose n}$$
Expading the fraction $\boldsymbol{\frac{k}{n}}$ by a factor of 2, we would like to show:
$$2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k}{2n}{2n \choose n+k}={2n \choose n}$$

Combinatorial Bijection
Observe that the left hand side is combinatorically equivalent to the number of walks on the integer line $\mathbb{Z}$, comprised of $2n$ steps, that never return to the origin.
To show this, we first divide into disjoint subsets, of positive/negative non-returning paths. Due to the symmetry around the origin, this corresponds to the factor of 2 outside the sum, and we focus on positive non-returning paths, W.L.O.G.
Continuing with the cycle lemma, also used similarly in a proof of Catalan numbers, we get that the number of non-returning ("dominant") paths with $n+k$ right-steps steps and $n-k$ left steps ($k>0)$, is:
$$\frac{2k}{2n}{2n \choose n+k}$$
And hence the entire sum:
$$2\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{2k}{2n}{2n \choose n+k}}$$
Therefore, all we need to show is that the number of non-returning paths is ${2n \choose n}$.
Counting the Complement
Instead of counting all non-returning paths of $2n$ steps, we will count the complement, i.e., all returning (at some point) paths of $2n$ steps.
Any path whose first return to the origin is at step $k$, is:

Either positive or negative up to step $2k$.
Returns to the origin at step $2k$.

And afterwards can take any path with the remaining steps.
Notice that the first two criteria give a description of a Dyck word with 2k-2 steps (the first and last steps are known), which can be counted with Catalan numbers (we multiply by 2 due to symmetry):
$$2 C_{k-1} = \frac{2}{k}{2k-2 \choose k-1}$$
After this we can take any combination of $2^{2n-2k}$.
Thus, we'd like to show:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{2\cdot C_{k-1}\cdot 2^{2n-2k}}=2^{2n}-{2n \choose n}$$
This can be proved by induction:
Base: $2 \cdot C_0 \cdot 2^0 = 2^2 - {2 \choose 1}$
Induction Hypothesis:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{2\cdot C_{k-1}\cdot 2^{2n-2k-2}}=2^{2n-2}-{2n-2 \choose n-1}$$
Induction Step:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{2\cdot C_{k-1}\cdot 2^{2n-2k}}=2C_{n-1}\cdot 2^0 + 4\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{1\cdot C_{k-1}\cdot 2^{2n-2k-2}}$$
By the induction hypothesis:
$$=2C_{n-1}\cdot 2^0 + 4(2^{2n-2}-{2n-2 \choose n-1})=2^{2n}-{2n \choose n}$$
Q.E.D.

You might be interested in a more bijective proof that the number of non-returning paths is equal to $\binom{2n}n$. This question has answers with two such bijective proofs: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4748477/
